# Running Vaadin-based Portlet in Liferay

Tags: liferay, vaadin

got an " Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vaadin.ui.CustomComponent " 
when trying to run a vaadin-portlet in liferay .

Comment: Full stack strace will help the community to help you with problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that in your liferay-plugin-package.properties file you have specified vaadin.jar in your portal-dependency-jars= property.  It should look like this:

```
name=Vaadin
module-group-id=liferay
module-incremental-version=1
tags=
short-description=
change-log=
page-url=http://www.liferay.com
author=Liferay, Inc.
licenses=
portal-dependency-jars=vaadin.jar
```